# Display google map with fragment/activity

Tags: android

I am trying to display a google maps, I havent used fragments much so I suspect that is where my problem is..

My java class for LocatorMap.java is:

```
public class LocatorMap extends Fragment {

    MapView m;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // inflat and return the layout
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_locator_map, container, false);
        m = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        m.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        m.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        m.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        m.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        m.onLowMemory();
    }
```

and my activity xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mapView" />
```

And I am trying to present the view like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocatorMap.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

When I do this I get:

```
Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{my package name.LocatorMap}
```

and `cannot cast to android.app.Activity`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class LocatorMap extends Fragment {
```

Its not a Activity class and you can't use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocatorMap.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

What you need is a container in the activity layout to which you add the fragment.

More info

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Generally container is a `FrameLayout`. Add a `FrameLayout` with id `fragment_container` in activity xml and have the following code in Activity class.

```
LocatorMap  newFragment = new LocatorMap() ;
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null); // if you want fragment to be added to backstack
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Do I put this code in the onCreate method of my activiy class?